# Changing the index of a combobox in Excel from C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, combobox

I am writing a program that accesses an excel template containing columns of data (with an unique ID number in the first column). Based on the first two numbers of the ID number, the row will either be kept or deleted.   In the template, this unique ID number column feeds an ActiveX Combobox's (located on the Worksheet) ListFill attribute.  When the non-matching rows are removed, the ListFill attribute is reset, but the text is not reset.

Example, if I select rows based on '02' being the first two numbers of the unique ID in Column A, I have no problem removing everything that does not start with '02' but the Combobox text still reads "010001" since that is the first Unique ID in the template, even though it doesn't exist in the new list.

I tell you all this to ask if anyone knows a better way to access the combobox?  I can access it as an OLEObject, but that does not allow me to change the index or text properties of the combobox as they are 'read only' as per the following intellisense error in VS 2013:

> Property or Indexer 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel_OLEObject.Index' cannot be assinged to -- it is read only.

The error appears on the line:

> oleobj.Index = 1;

The code snippet is below.  The current Excel application is passed as xlApp and the array comboboxes is passed.  Each member of the comboboxes array contains the sheet name the combobox is on, the name of the control and the ListFillRange it has on the template.  Example array member would be:

> Sheet1!:cbTest:$A$1:$A$10

```
private void ResetComboBoxes2(string[] comboboxes, Excel.Application xlApp)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet wksht = new Excel.Worksheet();
        Excel.Range rng;
        int listEndCellNum;
        string listEndCellApha;
        string listEndCell;

        for (int i = 0; i < comboboxes.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] comboBoxesSplit = comboboxes[i].Split(':');
            string sheetName = comboBoxesSplit[0].ToString();
            string oleObjName = comboBoxesSplit[1].ToString();
            string[] rangeArray = comboBoxesSplit[2].Split(':');
            string rangeStart = rangeArray[0];
            listEndCellNum = wksht.Range[rangeStart].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlDown].Offset[1, 0].Row - 1;
            string[] cellBreakdown = rangeStart.Split('$');
            listEndCellApha = cellBreakdown[1];
            listEndCell = "$" + listEndCellApha + "$" + listEndCellNum;
            string listFull = rangeStart + ":" + listEndCell;
            wksht = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[sheetName];

            foreach (Excel.OLEObject oleobj in wksht.OLEObjects())
            {
                if (oleobj.Name.ToString() == oleObjName)
                {
                    oleobj.ListFillRange = listFull;
                    oleobj.Index = 1;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I'm not even sure there IS a way to do this properly.  I could always make a chunk of VBA code to reset it before saving and access that through C# but I am hoping to do it here.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure out that I was doing too much thinking.   I went back to VBA then transposed that back to C#.  The result was the following code, which yu will notice is considerably shorter and succinct.  I had to test the oleObject's programID which for ALL activeX comboboxes is "Forms.ComboBox.1" then grab that object's name, then call it by name, with an extra "Object" in there for good measure.

```
 private void ResetComboBoxes2(string[] comboboxes, Excel.Application xlApp)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet wksht = new Excel.Worksheet();

        for (int i = 0; i < comboboxes.Length; i++)
        {
                string[] comboBoxesSplit = comboboxes[i].Split(':');
                string sheetName = comboBoxesSplit[0].ToString();
                wksht = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[sheetName];

                foreach (Excel.OLEObject oleobj in wksht.OLEObjects())
                {
                    if (oleobj.progID == "Forms.ComboBox.1")//oleobj.Name.ToString() == oleObjName)
                    {
                        string cbName = oleobj.Name.ToString();
                        wksht.OLEObjects(cbName).Object.ListIndex = 0;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```